# Loop to copy-paste columns copies them more times than desired

Tags: excel, loops, macros, vba

I have several databases (table) in different workbooks and, for each table, need to copy several specific columns into a single sheet. In addition, Each column should be pasted in an specific column of the recipient/master worksheet. As i am new with macros, I am writing my code step by step. Up to know, I have the code copy the columns of one table and paste it in the master table. However, the columns are being copied 3 times, the same column below the previous one, and I don't know why. I solely want the column copied once.

The following is the code

```
Dim f As Range, WB As Workbook
Dim arrSht, Arrcol As Variant, j As Long

arrSht = Array("a","b","c")
Arrcol = Array(5, 6, 8)

Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
     "C:\Users\gustavo\Documents\Minambiente\TUA\2015\CARDER\CARDER.xls")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
 End With

For j = LBound(arrSht) To UBound(arrSht)

  Set f = WB.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(arrSht(j), searchorder:=xlByRows, LookAt:=xlPart)

 If Not f Is Nothing Then
    WB.Sheets(1).Range(f.Offset(1, 0), Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, Arrcol(j)).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
      Else
      MsgBox arrSht(j) & "Header not found!"
 End If

  With Application
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  .DisplayAlerts = False
  End With
Next j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the structure or the contents of your file. But it seems to me that your problem comes from the use of LookAt: = xlPart. Because during the first iteration, if one of the cells in the search range contains an "a", then

```
If Not f Is Nothing Then
```

is checked. 
and during the second iteration, if one of the cells contains the letter "b"

```
If Not f Is Nothing Then
```

condition is checked. 
And so on...
Try using :

```
LookAt: = xlWhole.
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thank you! I checked again and it was my newbie mistake. I had run the code three times :P

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I checked the code again and it was my newbie mistake. I had run the code three times :P